How to install react on github repo remotely from a node server?
I have a project with a client and server side. On the client-side, users get authenticated in github, and then select a template thumbnail, and then we sent a token and the template details to the node service side, where a new repository is generated in github. So, far, I have created this pipeline and it works fine. A new repo is generated, but it's empty.. I need react to be installed in the newly generated repository, but I can't make it work.
This is the relevant function in my node server that generates the repo:
async function createRepository(authAccessToken, repositoryName, repositoryDescription, repositoryFramework, templateName) { 
  const accessToken = authAccessToken;
  const repoName = repositoryName;
  const repoDescription = repositoryDescription;
  const repoFramework = repositoryFramework;
  console.log(templateName, repoFramework)

  const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };
  
  const data = {
    'name': repoName,
    'description': repoDescription,
    'private': false
  };
  
  const response = fetch('https://api.github.com/user/repos', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if(data.html_url) { 
      console.log(`Repository created: ${data.html_url}`)
      return data.html_url;
    } else {
      console.log('Failed to generate repository')
      return null;
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(`Error creating repository: ${error}`));

  if(response) { 
    return response;
  } else { 
    return null;
  }
}

I have tried several things:
I tried adding this:
const repoDir = `./${repoName}`;
  fs.mkdirSync(repoDir);
  
  exec(`cd ${repoDir} && npx create-react-app ./`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      
      return null;
    }

  });

It didn't work.
I tried:
console.log('Creating React app...');
await runCommand('npm', ['exec', 'create-react-app', '.'], { cwd: repoDir });
console.log('React app created successfully.');
Also didn't work..
I tried a few other similar adjustments, but it doesn't work. For some I would get an error like: Error: spawn npm ENOENT.. for others I don't get any errors, the repo is just empty..
I tried increasing the time of the exec() so it doesn't time out while react is being generated, but it seems that the server restarts after a few seconds after exec() is invoked.. not really sure what is the problem, and if the timing out is the problem.
